# How to redirect output of awk to a file?

Tags: redirect, awk

I have this awk command to replace the occurrance of "proto" in file.txt by strings found in replacement.txt,

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[++i]=$0; next} /proto/{sub(/proto/, a[++j])} 1' replacement.txt file.txt
```

It works perfectly, but the original file is not edited. I used >> to redirect it to file, but the output is not redirected

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[++i]=$0; next} /proto/{sub(/proto/, a[++j])} 1' replacement.txt file.txt >> "file.txt"
```

Could anybody give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Her is how you do it with `awk`

```
awk 'some program' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

For your data:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[++i]=$0; next} /proto/{sub(/proto/, a[++j])} 1' replacement.txt file.txt > tmp && mv tmp file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

With gawk > 4.1:

```
gawk -i inplace 'FNR==NR{a[++i]=$0; next} /proto/{sub(/proto/, a[++j])} 1' replacement.txt file.txt
```

If you don't have this feature, use a temporary filename, then `mv temp file.txt`

Comment: This needs `gnu awk >= 4.1`